# Как правильно собрать WebArchive?

Tags: java, test-automation

Пытаюсь разобраться с arquillian.
Собираю WebArchive.

```
File[] files = Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml")
  .importRuntimeDependencies().resolve().withTransitivity().asFile();
```

Потом

```
WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
                  .addAsLibraries(files);
```

У меня из помки тянуться зависимости на другие модули. Мне их включать нужно, но  заменить к примеру persistence.xml или исключить класc. Как это сделать?